# JPanel - Set only a minimum height

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, minimum-size

I read that if a minimum size has not been set on a jpanel, a call to getMinimumSize will be delegated to the panel's layout manager. If a minimum size is set on a panel, then this dimension will be returned when getMinimumSize is called, and not the layout manager's. I want to set only a minimum height on my JPanel and leave the retrieval of the minimum width to the panel's layout manager, as I want to leave the minimum width to be whatever the layout manager decides. Is it possible to set only the minimum height on the JPanel?

Comment: What is it that determines or sets the minimum height?

Comment: don't interfere with what the LayoutManager decides, instead use a LayoutManager that does what you want :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `getMinimumSize()` method. In the method call `super` and replace the height in the result.

Comment: If this does work in term of code, it will not work in terms of layout because the layout manager computing the minimum size has no idea that you forced the height to  something different. If you want to force the height of the minimum size, you should implement your owne layout manager so that it takes that into account

Comment: A layout manager does compute the minimum size of the container it manages, not the components inside that container. Overriding getMinimumSize() should work (assuming the layout manager respects it).

Comment: @StanislavL Not a useful answer.  You should tell us how and give some example code in your answer.